# What is the Compile Error with VBA Code outlining

Tags: vba, ms-word, blueprism

I am getting a compile error when trying to include a timeout as part of the Save as action for Microsoft word on Blue Prism.

Code Stage:

```
ExecWithTimeout(Timeout, "Save As",
Sub()
Dim doc as Object = GetDocument(handle,documentname)
doc.SaveAs(filename)
newname = doc.name
End Sub)
```

Error:

```
 Page: Save As
 Stage: SaveAs
 Type: Error
 Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 1: 'ExecWithTimeout' is not declared. It may be 
inaccessible due to its protection level.
Repairable: No
```

Comment: There's no such function (`ExecWithTimeout`) in MS Word VBA.

Comment: This Function works with Excel? Is this unique to Excel?

Comment: Nope ;( This is also unknown function in Excel.

Comment: I have this working with Excel Saves As. (This is in a Blue Prism VBO - that interacts with Word & Excel)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, Prism<>VBA ;(

Comment: Yes but it uses VB Code. Thanks for your help

Comment: pretty sure there is a timeout function in BP vba, I used it myself for running macros.

Comment: Yes its in Excel VBO, looking to add it to the word VBO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly indicated, the Blue Prism MS Excel VBO contains the custom `ExecWithTimeout` function, but the same is *not* included by default in the MS Word VBO.

The solution for you might be to copy the entire `Private Sub ExecWithTimeout` block from the Global Code tab within the MS Excel VBO's Business Object Properties window:

[image]

Once copied, you can paste it into the same Global Code tab for the MS Word VBO.

However, modifying the default VBOs is generally a ***very bad idea*** as future releases of the Blue Prism platform will likely overwrite your customizations. I would implore you to review [the guidance on modifying these VBOs](https://www.scribd.com/document/416087167/Extending-MS-Excel-VBO-PDF) before continuing.